# Padding overrides height of the element with box-sizing: border-box

Tags: html, css

In snippet below `padding-top` overrides the `height` and `max-height` properties of container:

I want this `<div>` to be 10px high, but its 100px because of `padding-top`

as far as I understand this should be solved by box-sizing: border-box but this doesn't help

> [**w3schools** - border-box: the width and height properties (and min/max properties)
>   includes content, padding and border, but not the margin](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

```css
.padding-test {
  background: linear-gradient(109deg, #3adffd, #00abfb);
  outline: 1px solid #3b3c6d;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  max-height: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class='padding-test'></div>
```

Can someone explain why is this happening and how to fix this? 
Same happens for `width` and `padding-left`

**UPD:** I faced this issue when tried to change max height for box sized by [aspect-ratio approach](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/). I solved initial issue by setting parent size, but I still want to understand how `border-box` works with the `padding` - does it shrinks only content? is this correct behavior?  is there any solution for this exact situation - can I override padding somehow?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `border-box` does not change anything because you have a top padding that exceeds the defined height of the element. Do you mean to use margin top instead? I feel that this might be an XY problem: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Terry @Thielicious I faced this issue when tried to change max height for box sized by aspect-ratio approach. that issue is solved, but I want to understand the `border-box` behavior

Comment: If you inspect the element, you see that it is 100px high. `border-box` includes the padding in the height calculation, so what you're saying in your CSS is: make this element 10px high, including 100px padding. This renders as a height of 100px

Comment: padding doesn't collapse if you set max-height. there is no max-padding or what so ever you expect  to fit in what you suppose to be the box-sizing:border-box setup. :(

Answer (score 1):

I had run into the same doubt. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#border-box):

> **border-box**
> The width and height properties include the content, padding, and border, but do not include the margin. Note that padding and border will be inside of the box. For example, .box {width: 350px; border: 10px solid black;} renders a box that is 350px wide, with the area for content being 330px wide. ***The content box can't be negative and is floored to 0, making it impossible to use border-box to make the element disappear.***

so `box-sizing: border-box` doesn't mean you can set the "border box" directly, but only affects how "content box" is calculated, which cannot be negative.

And my solution is: avoid the paddings, use a height-holding div or `::before` pseudo element with designated height instead. (may also need `overflow: hidden`.) For example:

```css
.padding-test {
  height: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.padding-test::before {
  height: 100px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```